# why do i lose my hidden field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some hidden fields on my page, all of which work fine apart from one.  I am setting the value in document.ready, before calling buildGrid() :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CDServices.asmx/GetWeekEndingDates",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function(msg) {

            //store default dates in hidden fields
            $("#<%=hdnCurrentDate.ClientID%>").val(msg.d.CurrentDate);
            $("#<%=hdnLastWeekEndingDate.ClientID%>").val(msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate);
        }
    });

    buildGrid();

});
```

Yet in buildGrid, the value in the hidden field is empty :

```
 function buildGrid() {

    alert($("#<%=hdnLastWeekEndingDate.ClientID%>").val());
```

I call other functions on button clicks where the hidden field value is picked up fine, why does the value disappear here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call buildGrid() inside the success function. Otherwise it will be called when the request is still running and your hidden fields are not yet filled.

Comment: Thanks...annoying that I didn't spot it myself!